# Firefox addon SDK enable/disable when click on toolbarbutton

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

i have problem when i programming my addon, i try to add button in toolbarbutton and when user click on button, the extension disable and reverse...

```
var buttons = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

exports.main = function(options, callbacks)
{
    console.log(options.loadReason);

    var button  = buttons.ActionButton(
    {
        id    : "ext_toolbarbutton",
        label : "Ext",
        icon  : {
        "16" : "./img/gear_16.png",
        "32" : "./img/gear_32.png",
        "64" : "./img/gear_64.png"
        },
        onClick : function(){onUnload("disable");}
    });
};

exports.onUnload = function(reason) {
    console.log(reason);
    // same button but he call the main function !
};
```

and i have the error :
ReferenceError: onUnload is not defined

an idea ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write some code that disables a specific add-on, using the AddonManager API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager

Note that you would never be able to then *re-enable* the add-on, because the button you created would be removed when the add-on is disabled. Unless I misunderstand you.

Comment: button remain active ! it is grayed out as firefbug eg, have you an example for me to see how to use this addonManager ?

Comment: I linked to the documentation for the AddonManager, there are examples there.